# Perfectly align top of cells in tabularx

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tabularx, two-column

With the following code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{xskak,adjustbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[5]

\begingroup\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\colorbox{lightgray}{%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{p{0.5\linewidth}@{\extracolsep{\fill}}p{0.46\linewidth}@{}}%
\adjustbox{valign=t,width=0.85\linewidth}{\chessboard[setfen=8/8/5K2/2p3Bk/2P1R3/8/8/8 b - - 0 1,tinyboard,margin=false]} & \footnotesize{\lipsum[5]} 
\end{tabularx}}
\endgroup

\lipsum[5]

\lipsum[5]

\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

I get the following result :

[image: result]

As you can see the text is not perfectly top aligned with the chessboard on the left side... It is slightly shifted down...

I would like to align the top of the chessboard perfectly with the top of the text on the right, but I couldn't do it... Can you help me please?

Thank you!

Comment: switch the order of the keys: `\adjustbox{width=0.85\linewidth,valign=t}`. And if you still don't like the alignment, change `\adjboxvtop`, see the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a solution based on two nested minipages, side by side, both set to the top alignment. `adjustbox` is very convenient macro, which correctly set the image baseline but it has to be corrected by redefined `adjboxvtop`.

Here's the code. Note I have added a small padding to the `colorbox`.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{xskak,adjustbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{parskip}

\renewcommand{\adjboxvtop}{1ex}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[5]

\begingroup
\setlength{\fboxsep}{3pt}
\colorbox{lightgray}{%
  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
      \hspace{0.5em}%
      \adjustbox{width=0.8\linewidth,valign=t}{%
        \chessboard[%
          setfen=8/8/5K2/2p3Bk/2P1R3/8/8/8 b - - 0 1,
          tinyboard,
          margin=false,
        ]}
    \end{minipage}%
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.46\linewidth}
      \footnotesize
      \lipsum[5]
    \end{minipage}
  \end{minipage}}
\endgroup

\lipsum[5]

\lipsum[5]

\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

[image]