# Stretch xskak chessboard to the width of a multicol column (inside a twocolumn article itself)

Tags: multicol, justification, xskak

With the following code :

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[5]

\begin{multicols}{2}
\chessboard[setfen=8/8/5K2/2p3Bk/2P1R3/8/8/8 b - - 0 1,tinyboard,margin=false,showmover=false]\footnotesize{\lipsum[1]}
\end{multicols}

\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

I get the following result :

[image]

I would like the chessboard to span the entire width of the column, and the text that follows not to bite into the a-h letters of the chessboard files...

I would also like the 1-8 rank numbers of the chessboard not to be shifted to the left but to be aligned with the left side of the column...

I have not managed to achieve this ... Your help is welcome! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that using a `multicols` environment inside a `twocolumn` layout is a good idea (and the package issues a warning, so I guess, you should be very careful), but you can actually make use of the good ideas from [this nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/676865/47927) to your previous question and do something like the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{xskak,adjustbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{multicol}

\renewcommand{\adjboxvtop}{1ex}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[5]

\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
    \hfill%
    \adjustbox{width={\linewidth-0.5em},valign=t}{%
      \chessboard[%
        setfen=8/8/5K2/2p3Bk/2P1R3/8/8/8 b - - 0 1,
        tinyboard,
        margin=false,
        showmover=false
      ]}%
  \end{minipage}\par%
  \footnotesize
  \lipsum[5]
\end{multicols}

\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! Exactly what I needed. 
I’ll make the effort to understand how I could come up with such a solution by myself…

Comment: Is there a mode or a package in LaTeX that draws the outline of all boxes ? That’d be helpful for debugging…

Comment: @halogenr You could try with `\fbox`, but it adds some padding. But see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2083/47927